# Foundation Reflow causes error if called from Knockout custom binding with data-tooltip and an HTML comment in markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, zurb-foundation

Accompanying jsFiddle with reproduction of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ComradeF/M9e94/

I am using Foundation and Knockout together on a project. One of the challenges I faced was that when new [tabs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html) needed to be rendered, Knockout would comply, but clicking the tabs wouldn't do anything. The solution to that was a call to `$(document).foundation('reflow')` in a custom binding. Unfortunately, that solution may be either insufficient or just plain wrong, as it is now associated with an error I am receiving.

I tried to add [tooltips](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html) to the tabs and some of their content via the `data-tooltip` attribute in my markup, only to get errors on line 1422 of jQuery 2.1.0. That line is `elem.getAttribute( name )`, and the error is `undefined is not a function`. In this situation, `elem` is a comment, and thus has no `getAttribute()` function.

The error can be eliminated either by removing the comment (`<!-- this is a comment -->`) in the markup, or by removing the `data-tooltip` attribute in the tab's link.

I realize the quick fix is for me to remove the HTML comments from my markup, but I feel like this may be a symptom of something worse lurking... so I'd prefer to investigate and solve rather than take the easy way out.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same problem (except I am working on an Angular js project).

I have not been able to find a solution yet but I have found a work around. If anyone knows a good solution please let me know.

My work around was to reduce the scope of the `$(document).foundation('reflow');` to avoid any html comments elements (which are unfortunately necessary and common in Angular js apps).

e.g. `$(element.find("nav")).foundation('tooltip', 'reflow');` This at least stops the errors happening in my specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing this using [sacumminis's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987044/sacummins) solution - that removed the exception but it also made my tooltips stop working.

However this [thread had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408501/ng-repeat-sorting-is-throwing-an-exception-in-jquery) a solution by [Ayush Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502801/ayush-gupta) which worked perfectly. I'm using this with Angular rather than Knockout so I simply put it early in my app.js file. What you need to do is add this chunk of code somewhere early in your app code:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createComment('')).getAttribute = function() {}
```

The error is now gone and tooltips work well. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This isn't really a solution IMHO. It's just a hack that stops the error from showing up. The real problem is, that some code calls `getAttribute` on a comment node. And that seems to be related to `data-tooltip` and the `reflow` function.

Comment: @britter I fully agree. But in my case I really wasn't sure which part of which framework was calling it and didn't have enough time to investigate further to report/fix/patch the bug.