# ng-repeat sorting is throwing an exception in jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, exception, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table with rows created by ng-repeat.  Table headers have an ng-click that sets the predicate for the sorting (the function also determines direction, asc/desc).  The sorting works fine, but for some reason I get exceptions from jQuery every time I change the predicate and the sort fires.

Here is a plunkr example of what I am doing : http://plnkr.co/edit/qfNcm9RPQSsNgqmm3TYS?p=preview

As you can see in the plnkr, the ng-repeat is pretty simple.  The ng-repeat in our project is similar and not any more complicated.

```
<tr ng-repeat="contest in AllContests | orderBy:sort:ReverseSort" ng-show="contest.isVisible">
```

This actually happens in a number of places in our code and we use different methods of sorting among them, but they are still affected.

The table headers can be clicked to sort the items.  That plunkr does not exhibit the problem.  Even though the sorting works on my page, it breaks other things on the page (like a [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) control).  The exception is on line 1430 in jquery.js (ver 2.1.1 via Google CDN which includes Sizzle.js).  The method in which the exception happens is Sizzle.attr.  It looks like what is happening is it is looping through all of the elements created with the ng-repeat, and getting attribute values from them.  The exception happens when it gets to the " end ngRepeat: contest in AllContests | orderBy:sort:ReverseSort " comment that signifies the end of the ng-repeat section.

Specifically I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' when it tries to getAttribute() on the element.

```
return val !== undefined ?
    val :
    support.attributes || !documentIsHTML ?
        elem.getAttribute( name ) :
        (val = elem.getAttributeNode(name)) && val.specified ?
            val.value :
            null;
```

Now, I could pull jquery, add it to my project edit it so that it evaluates elem.nodeName == "#comment", and just return null in that case.  I would much rather know if I am doing something incorrectly or if there is a better way of doing this.

Otherwise, is there a way of overriding that method and supplying my own without editing the jquery library?

## EDIT

Here is an example of the problem in action:
https://playmlf.com/Lobby/ContestLobby

## Temporary Resolution

I have edited the jQuery library so that it looks thusly:

```
Sizzle.attr = function (elem, name) {
    if (elem.nodeName == '#comment') return null;
    // Set document vars if needed
    if ( ( elem.ownerDocument || elem ) !== document ) {
        setDocument( elem );
    }
```

NOTE: this is only the top portion of the Sizzle.attr method.  The first `if` is the line of interest.  It returns null if the element is a comment.  I did not want to edit the jquery library, but I was unable to figure out how to override this particular method, or keep it from being called in the first place during a sort.  I don't like this fix, but at the same time I have spent WAY too much time on this and need something that works.  I will pay the bad fix tax later.

Comment: why u need jquery at all?

Comment: The site is in transition into angular, and the previous incarnation of the site used jQuery very heavily. it will be quite some time before the entire site is no longer reliant on jquery.

Comment: How can we help if you did not reproduce the problem in the plunker?

Comment: Could not figure out how to add the jquery library in question to the plnkr.  I do know of a page that exhibits the problem though.  I will add it to the question.

Comment: So the problem here is that Sizzle.attr assumes that passed element supports getAttribute. I've reported a bug here: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/309

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to occur because Comment element does not have getAttribute method.

There is [a bug](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/309) logged for this. As a workaround, you can add this to your codebase and make sure that it gets executed early on:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createComment('')).getAttribute = function() {}
```

Comment: This is great but this doesn't work for IE8 because IE8 doesn't have `.getPrototypeOf`. I tried using `window[document.createComment('').constructor.toString().match(/(function|object)\s+([A-Z][^\s(\]]+)/)[2]];` to get the prototype from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11204952/1376627) but I get an "invalid pointer" error in IE8. Any ideas?